# Vuex state property is set to response from GET request. Function gives error because said property is apparently NULL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The application is a Vue.js SPA. As soon as it is started, a Vuex action is dispatched that makes a GET request to a JSON file and saves that JSON to a Vuex property called `champions`. Those actions are dispatched in the main App.vue file:

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted(){
            this.$store.dispatch('getChampions')
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is my store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        champions: null
    },
    mutations: {
        champions(state, data){
            state.champions = data.champions
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getChampions({commit, state}){
            axios.get("https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.14.1/data/en_US/champion.json")
            .then((response) => {
                commit('champions', {
                    champions: response.data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Now here comes my actual problem. I have a component that has a data property `championsInfo: this.$store.state.champions` and a function that loops through the array and find me the champion with a certain id:

```
data(){
    return {
        championsInfo: this.$store.state.champions,
    }
},
methods: {
    findChampionName(id){
        let championId = id.toString();
        let champion = Object.entries(this.championsInfo).find(([key,value]) => value.key === championId);

        return champion[1]
    }
}
```

Now, if I load a different component first and then head to the one that uses that function, everything works fine, however, if I go straight to that component, I get an error `"Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object""` and I believe that is because the `championsInfo` property at the time of the function execution is null because of the GET request. Sadly I'm not sure how to avoid that.

I'm also not sure if this matters, however, the function is used like this:

```
<img class='champion-icon' :src="'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.13.1/img/champion/' + findChampionName(participant.championId).image.full" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE :**

here is a codesandbox for a fixed version : https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-eclk1

After running your app on my local machine i found out that your code includes the following issue :

**why you were getting the error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"** ?

When your `App.vue` component was rendered...the components inside its template must be also rendered obviously ...so your child component that includes the method `findChampionName()` was rendered before even the `championsInfo` is available yet so the reason why you were getting that error is because of `Object.entries(championsInfo)` throws it cause `championsInfo` was null.

**how to fix this ?**

you just have to add a `v-if` to your component tag inside its parent with the condition of `$store.state.champions` so only if that object is ready (available) the component will be rendered

```
<champion-comp v-if="$store.state.champions"></chmapion-comp>
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to change a thing. Unfortunately I can't even figure out why since these asynchronous shenanigans are boggling my mind.

Comment: @Bobimaru adapt that to your app... if you still getting the error reply to me because i also changed the input of `findChampionName()` cause i don't have `participant.championId` ..you can notice the changes on the template i included

Comment: This actually worked but there's just one thing though. <router-view> is used to render the matched component for the given path so I had to add the condition like that <router-view v-if='$store.state.champions'></router-view>, however, it seems to me that this way, a component which might not require $store.state.champions might not get rendered if $store.state.champions is null. Is this an issue?

Comment: @Bobimaru Ah , i didn't know that you are using `vue-router` in this case just remove the `v-if` from your `<router-view>` tag and put it inside your component template on the root container like : `<template><div v-if='$store.state.champions'>...</div></template>`